# mysql windows 2003 defrag harddisk

Tags: mysql

We have a windows 2003 server with MySQL 5.1 installed. Since a few days the mysqldump is almost 1 hour slower than normal. The total size of the databases was growing with approx. 1 MB per day. Not much differences.

Our technical support guy can't find strange things on our machine. He says that it would be a good idea to defrag our server with MySQL on it. I never thought about defragmentation but I have Defraggler installed. After anaylizing it says 80% fragmentation!

Could that be the issue / reason why the dump's are getting slower with almost 1 hour ?
My first idea was that some windows update may be the reason.

Please sent me your thoughts

And is it wise to do a defragmentation on a MySQL production server?? 
Defraggler says deframentation could take more than 1 day ?

Answer (score 0):

Your database dump is probably disk-bound, meaning that the is limited by accessing data on the disk.

If the data on the disk is highly fragmented, it can significantly affect the performance.  Depending on the layout of the data on the disk, MySQL may be filling in lots of small gaps in the disk with the new data, which will be much slower to work with than large contiguous blocks of data.

Regular defragmentation is a good idea.  However, since MySQL likely has a lock on the data files for your databases, it may be necessary to shut down MySQL to defragment its files.

I suggest at least running defraggler without shutting down MySQL to defragment as much as possible.  I'm not familiar with defraggler, but if it makes it possible, try to find out if MySQL's data is fragmented.  It might have a table of fragmented files or a graphical view of the data on the disk.  The MySQL data files will probably be some of the largest files so that might make it easier to find them.  If you find that its files are heavily fragmented, you may then want to try to find some time to shut down MySQL and defragment its files.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer , here a screenshot http://www.kleinhandel.nl/pic.png defragmentation or not?

Comment: @user2783635 Look in the File List tab and see if the MySQL data files are fragmented.

Comment: all mysql files are fragmented